# Filter Dataframe columns based on list

Tags: pandas, list, python-itertools

I have a list with numbers and I want to find all the different combinations of these numbers without repetition. 
From there, the next step is to filter columns of a dataframe df by column numbers; the column numbers being the combinations previously found. Then I have to run some calculations on the new filtered dataframe at each iteration.

Let's assume I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import itertools

lst = [1, 2, 3] #intial list
    for i in range(1,4) #combs can have 1, 2 or 3 numbers  
        combs = [] #empty list to store combinations
        els = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(lst, i)]
        for j in range(0,len(els)): #loop through each combination found
                temp_list=els[j]
                temp_df=df.iloc[:temp_list]

                #...Do some calculations with temp_df#
```

Running this code, I obtain the following error:cannot do slice indexing on  with these indexers [[1]] of class 'list'

I think **els** in my code is a list of list (and temp_list) as well. So I tried to flatten those to obtain a list (this topic has been covered here for instance: [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python))

However, when running this line

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in temp_list for item in sublist]
```

I obtain a new error: 'int' object is not iterable. 
How can I obtain a list of numbers that I can use to filter my dataframe? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]], columns=[1, 2, 3])
```

Giving:

```
   1  2  3
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

The following code should achieve what you want. Note that I am using `.loc` here, not `.iloc`, since I am specifying the column **names** not the **indices**. If you want to specify the indices, then use `.iloc`.

```
import itertools

#Initial list
lst = [1, 2, 3]

#Assemble all combinations
combs = [list(x) for i in range(1,4) for x in itertools.combinations(lst, i)]

#Use .loc
for comb in combs: #For each combination
    temp_df = df.loc[:,comb]
    print(temp_df)
```

Yields:

```
   1
0  0
1  3
2  6 

   2
0  1
1  4
2  7 

   3
0  2
1  5
2  8 

   1  2
0  0  1
1  3  4
2  6  7 

   1  3
0  0  2
1  3  5
2  6  8 

   2  3
0  1  2
1  4  5
2  7  8 

   1  2  3
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. Thanks for the explanation on iloc and loc as well, very helpful!